# Como colocar um option selected predefinido php

Tags: php

Boas queria que se o ano fosse 2012 colasse o valor com selected é possivel  fazer?

```
$ano[] = "<option value='$row[ano]'/>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está a solução.
Caso o ano seja 2012 a opção fica selected. Agora tem que garantir que o ano é 2012 apenas uma vez.

```
$ano[] = "<option ".($row[ano]=='2012'?'selected':'')." value='$row[ano]'/>"
```

Comment: `$row[ano]==12` isso não está certo, o ano vem com 4 dígitos, e ele não informou que está filtrando apenas os dois finais.

Comment: Obrigado, estava distraido. :)

Comment: não  da . estou usar o datalist sera por isso

Comment: ja consegui resolver...faltavam "" dentro da row

Comment: Foi util então? Se sim, optimo e bom "coding" ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Para capturar o ano atual, use

```
$anoAtual = date('Y');
```

Para fazer o que você quer, você pode usar as condições do PHP

```
<?php

$anoAtual = date('Y');

if ($anoAtual == $row['ano']) {
    $ano[] = "<option value='{$row['ano']}' selected>";
} else {
    $ano[] = "<option value='{$row['ano']}'>";
}
```

Ou assim

```
<?php

if ($row['ano'] == '2012') {
    $ano[] = "<option value='{$row['ano']}' selected>";
} else {
    $ano[] = "<option value='{$row['ano']}'>";
}
```

Tem muitas outras formas, mas isso tem que ser avaliado conforme suas necessidades. Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara.

Espero ter contribuido.

Comment: estou a usar um datalist se calhar é por isso q nao estava a conseguir

Comment: <input list ="anos" class="form-control" placeholder="Ano "type="search" id="ano" hidden="hidden" name="Ano" value="" />
                    <datalist id="anos" >
                    </datalist>